# How does the GUI load a partitioned table on remote server in dolphindb?

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb, distributed-database

How does the GUI load a partitioned table on remote server in dolphindb?

I run scripts in GUI and want to load a partitoned table which is on the remote server, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. The first method is to connect to the data node of the remote server, and then load it through the [loadTable()](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/l/loadTable.html) function.
2. Establish a connection with the remote server through the xdb function, and then execute the script on the remote node through the remoteRun function, and return the result. The sample code is as follows:

```py
//Establish a remote connection
conn = xdb( "115.239.209.234" , 28948 , "admin" , "123456" ) 

//Execute the script on the remote node, the list variable is on the remote server
remote Run(conn, "list =exec top 500 distinct(ID) from oadTable('dfs://DataDB','pt') where TradeDate=2019.09.06" ) 

//Load the pt table in DataDB on the remote server Part of the data in the current GUI connected to the data node (not belonging to the remote server) memory, the variable is t2
t2 = remote Run(conn, "select * from loadTable('dfs://DataDB','pt') where TradeDate=2019.09.06 a
```